# ErrorMessage in Excel

Tags: c#, com, excel-2003

i got a urgent problem with the following error, while setting the DisplayAlerts-property of the Excel ApplicationClass to false.

```
var excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

I get the following error message in the logs:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800AC472): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472
     at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass.set_DisplayAlerts(Boolean RHS)
     at Service.Dispose()
```

The following MessageBox is shown

[image]
<sub>(source: [xlam.ch](http://www.xlam.ch/xlimits/Nicht-genug-Speicher-fuer-vollstaendige-Anzeige.gif))</sub>

Any ideas on this case?

Regards
MacX

Comment: added a further row in log-trace. maybe dispose() is the cause? but why not always

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `DisplayAlerts` on the instance of `Excel.Application` you're working with. 
Something like this:

```
var excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Comment: @MacX then see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/9168f9f2-e5bc-4535-8d7d-4e374ab8ff09/). Basically they advise to wait and retry your call after a second when you get that error...

Comment: you're kidding. that's no real fix for this prob

Comment: @MacX yes, not a very exciting answer, I'm afraid... I hope someone can suggest a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to catch that error and re-submit whatever you were inserting into a cell on excel.  This is an annoying bug and I have not been able to implement and elegant solution for.

Someone can correct me if I am wrong but I cannot find a way to determine if Excel is in a "suspended" state or not besides catching this exception.  It's like an unavoidable race condition where you don't know the result until you know the result.  I searched for a way to solve this before giving up and implemented an ugly error checking solution.

Sorry, I hope someone has a better solution for this than me.