# COMException on Main Thread of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, comexception

WPF, Excel AddIn,  C#, 
I have multiple asychronous calls to get data from web service on main thread, then in call back, 
I will plot the data in Excel. I tracked call back and they run on main thread, too. 
but I still get COMException 0x800AC472, googled and it seems this is a multi-thread issue.

but I am confused why this happened. 
I think there is only one main thread and since all callback are run on main thread and there is no reason to have the exception?

Edit: 
On main UI thread, ribbon/button is clicked, it will call web service BuildMetaData,
once it is returned back, in its callback MetaDataCompleteCallback, another web service call is sent
Once it is returned back, in its callback DataRequestJobFinished, it will call plot to plot data on Excel.  see below

```
On Main UI class:
Btn_Click()
{
...
                       _reportObjs[index].GenerateReport();

}
```

on Class to GenerateReport

```
public void GenerateReport()
{
                Request.ParseFunction();
                Request.MetacompleteCallBack = MetaDataCompleteCallback;
                Request.BuildMetaData();
}

public void MetaDataCompleteCallback(int id)
{
            try
            {
                if (Request.IsRequestCancelled)
                {
                    Request.FormulaCell.Dispose();
                    return;
                }

                ErrorMessage = Request.ErrorMessage;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ErrorMessage))
                {
                    _queryJob = new DataQueryJob(UnityContainer, Request.BuildQueryString(), DataRequestJobFinished, Request);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModifyCommentOnFormulaCellPublishRefreshEvent();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                ModifyCommentOnFormulaCellPublishRefreshEvent();
            }
            finally
            {
                Request.MetacompleteCallBack = null;
            }
} 


        public void DataRequestJobFinished(DataRequestResponse response)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<DataRequestResponse>(DataRequestJobFinishedUI), response);
        }

        public void DataRequestJobFinished(DataRequestResponse response)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Request.IsRequestCancelled)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (response.status != Status.COMPLETE)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = ManipulateStatusMsg(response);
                }
                else // COMPLETE
                {
                    // TODO: Convert this into factory pattern
                    var tmpReq = Request as DataRequest;
                    if (tmpReq == null) return;

                    new VerticalTemplate(tmpReq, response, IsOffice2003).Plot();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrorMessage = e.Message;
                MIMICShared.Helper.LogError(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                //if (token != null)
                //    this.UnityContainer.Resolve<IEventAggregator>().GetEvent<DataQueryJobComplete>().Unsubscribe(token);
                ModifyCommentOnFormulaCellPublishRefreshEvent();
                Request.FormulaCell.Dispose();
            }
        }


        on plot class

        public void Plot()
        {
        ... 
           attributeRange.Value2 = headerArray;
           DataRange.Value2 = ....
           DataRange.NumberFormat = ... 
        }
```

Comment: How do you know all the callbacks are run on the main thread? What kind of callbacks do you get, and how do you serialize them to the main thread? Do you use a dispatcher? BeginInvoke?

Comment: thanks. I step in Visual Studio and see they are run on mainThread.

Comment: I called method A when a UI button/ribbon is clicked. in the method, I will call web servcie asynchronously with callback. In callback, I will plot

Comment: Post the code you use to marshal the callback to the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. I just edit my post to include code sample.

Comment: I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246288/errormessage-in-excel, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/9168f9f2-e5bc-4535-8d7d-4e374ab8ff09/  It seems there is no solution to the issue except wait/retry

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I saw this stackoverflow.com/questions/5246288/errormessage-in-excel, social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/… It seems there is no solution to the issue except wait/retry. 
THis post talks about how to check if Excel is in edit. http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/03/23/excel-check-user-edit-cell/

Comment: Hello, please let me know the right solution to the issue. I googled and did not find a better one. Thanks

Comment: I still have no solution except the linked above which says wait/retry