# how to ensure only one thread can access an instance of a collection type at a time

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

There are several places in my code (C#) which will modify a queue or a list. I want to make sure at any time there is only one thread modify the queue or list.  so How to keep its consistency in C#? thanks

Edit 
Please see sample code [COMException on Main Thread of WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566214/comexception-on-main-thread-of-wpf-application)

Answer (score 2):

Hold a mutex while accessing or modifying the queue or list.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `lock` statement.

```
    lock(myObject) {

    //Code

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several threadsafe types available in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace and elsewhere in the framework. Using these may be the simplest option.

You could also perform your own explicit locking using the [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx%28%29) statement. E.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly List<int> list = new List<int>();
    private readonly object locker = new object();

    public void SomeCommand(Bar bar)
    {
        lock (this.locker)
        {
            // do something here?
            this.list.Add(..);
            // do something here?
        }
    }

    public Baz SomeQuery()
    {
        lock (this.locker)
        {
            // do something here?
            this.list.Select(...);
            // do something here?
        }
    }

    public void SomethingElseEntirely()
    {
        lock (this.locker)
        {
            // do something here
        }            
    }
}
```

The best option varies from case to case. E.g. do you want to also synchronize operations other than just the collection manipulations (as indicated in the code sample), do you want to performance tune for more reads than writes or more writes than reads (some of the built in types are already tuned in these ways), etc.

You could also experiment with other explicit thread synchronization types, such as [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) which is optimised for more reads than writes, and see what fits your scenario best.

Comment: I'd like to synchronize colleciton manipulations and also execution of several code sections (where the collection is accessed), i.e. at any time only one section is run

Comment: A lock will work as advertised. What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I use lock in every section that need running exclusively and I still get COMException
Message:Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472, pls see sample code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566214/comexception-on-main-thread-of-wpf-application

Comment: I believe the COM exception is a separate problem from this question. This question is about synchronising thread access to lists and IMHO this has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on .NET 3 or later, the simplest solution is to use [SynchronizedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use built-in thread-safe collections such as [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).